# Does a stored password Break the ASP.NET CompareValidator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

I am trying to create a registration page for my company, and so I put down Password and "Repeat Password" textboxes on my form, along with a `CompareValidator`. It appears to work just fine, whenever users go into both fields, type data and click the Register/Submit button.

However, I've noticed an issue where my Firefox browser during testing saves a password that I entered. After it's saved the password, if I then go back to the page "fresh", it shows the password already filled in the Password field (though not in the "Repeat Password" field for some reason).

Anyways, if I then populate the e-mail address, I can then click the Register/Submit button with no issues at all!

[image: Site Registration Page]

The most concerning thing is, when I debug into the CodeBehind and even force a validation by triggering both the control's Validate method and the Page's Validate method manually, it still somehow PASSES the validation even though, as you can see in the QuickWatches in my screenshot below, the fields have two different values!

[image: Showing the three elements that I'm watching]

Have I found a bug that I should report to Microsoft, or is it possible that I did something wrong in setting this all up? All I did was plop the `CompareValidator` on the form, and set the "ControlToCompare" to "txtUserPass" and the "ControlToValidate" to "txtRepeatPass", and the Operation is set to "Equal".

Am I perhaps doing something wrong here, or have I found a genuine bug caused by browsers storing passwords?

Comment: You need to add `[Required]` to your `string txtRepeatPass` property. Because the value is empty the `[Compare]`  does not trigger.

Comment: Ah, thank you @Catalin I did actually have a separate RequiredFieldValidator on my form for the Repeat Password, but your comment made me look at it a second time, and I just discovered that it was pointing to the main Password field rather than the Repeat! So I fixed that up, and that fixed the issue! Strange behavior though that it doesn't still try to compare a blank to the other value though... I would think you'd still want to compare them. Can you put your comment as an answer, so I can mark it the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator?view=netframework-4.8), the `CompareValidator` does not trigger for empty values:

```
If the input control is empty, no validation functions are called and validation succeeds. 
Use a RequiredFieldValidator control to require the user to enter data in the input control.
```

You need to combine the `CompareValidator` with a `RequiredFieldValidator`.